# Gatsby PWA - Store data locally on the client side pouchDB or localStorage?

Tags: pouchdb, gatsby

I'm writing my first gatsby PWA with the starter gatsby-material-starter. The app should store some data like daily notes and appointments locally. The data will be kept on the client side only. I know I could use localStorage. What about pouchDB? Or what does fit best in the gatsby PWA world?